# how to use a common function an all controller in zend framework

Tags: php

I have declared a function

```
public function findexts($filename) {
    $filename = strtolower($filename);
    $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename);
    $n = count($exts) - 1;
    $exts = $exts[$n];
    return $exts;
}
```

i want to use this function in all my controller . how to declare that function and where to declare this function (i mean in which file ) without repeating code?

Comment: Define this function in models class and you can access this by referencing the class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about [helpers](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3350)

[Additional resource](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/using-action-helpers-in-zend-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

As Lele pointed out, you are looking at view helpers. But here is simpler version for your code:

```
public function findexts($filename) {
    return array_pop(split("[/\\.]", strtolower($filename));
}
```